# MVC + React authentication

Tags: asp.net-mvc, reactjs, authentication, identityserver4

I have an MVC application, what I eventually want to migrate to SPA react.
as a start, I tried to move some finctionality into a react app, what I embedde in the MVC app.
The only issue is authentication. I am using identity server 4 token server. The login is in MVC, I get the token in MVC correctly, that is ok. But somehow I should  have the token in redux store, and apex header. 
I tried this: https://github.com/maxmantz/redux-oidc
the problem is that it has it's own login screen.

Is there any other way? I.e. mvc token should be stored in a cookie, and I can see .AspNetCore.Identity.Application and .AspNet.Cookies, but these are not JWT tokens. How could I get it than from react?

thanks